# Calling mangled class instance methods from function marked extern C

Tags: c++, c, webassembly, name-mangling

I have a typically declared class:

```
class Task {
    public:
        int test(int &c);
};


int Task::test(int &c) {
    c += 8;
    return c;
}
```

For compiling to WASM, I was trying to instantiate this class and call the test method, like so:

```
extern "C" {
    Task t;

    int scratch() {
        int c = 123;
        t.test(c);
        return c;
    }
}
```

with `extern "C"` directive to prevent name mangling that makes exposing it difficult on the JS module.

However, compiling this program gives error `undefined symbol: _ZN4Task4testERi (referenced by top-level compiled C/C++ code)`, indicating that the "unmangled" `int scratch()` method cannot call the "mangled" `int Task::test(int &c)`. Wrapping the class definition and implementation with `extern "C"` produces the same output.

How could I best call `int Task::test(int &c)` on an instance from a function that is marked `extern "C"`?

Comment: I can't reproduce this. How exactly are you building this? Please provide all the steps needed to obtain the error, including which compiler you're using, and exactly how you invoke it.

Comment: @UnslanderMonica this shouldn't have been happening in standard compliant compiler. seems this WASM one follows quirks of Borland C++ (pre-Windows). Demangling should happen only on C-compliant declarations

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mangling is close to a hack that was invented to allow the low level linker to make a difference between `int foo(int)` and `int foo(void)`. You can use `extern "C"` to explicitely forbid mangling, but you declare symbols to have that linkage, so it should only be used for plain functions and not for classes nor class members.

The idiomatic way is to remember that a call to a non static member function carries a hidden `this` pointer. So you do not change anything to the `Task` class but declare a plain function to act as a relay:

```
extern "C" {
    int task_test(Task *obj, int *c) { // C language does not know about reference hence a pointer
        return obj->test(*c);
}
```

Comment: It seems like by exposing this and compiling, I am still getting the same error `undefined symbol: _ZN4Task4testERi (referenced by top-level compiled C/C++ code)` back. `c++filt` is returning `Task::test(int&)`, so I _seem_ to be calling it somewhere when I don't believe I am.

Comment: @Jemoka: then you have a linking problem. You should show how *exactly* you build your executable. Likely you are failing to provide the compilation unit that *defines* (and not only declare) `Task::test`.

Comment: @Jemoka or your environment requires dynamic linking but that symbol is not exported

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie yup. In addition to the problem noted by the original answer I also had a dynamic linking problem in my cmake. Silly me. Marking as resolved. Thanks all.